# I get access denied when I try to implement TwitterStream filter or sample function

Tags: java, twitter4j

I get access denied when I try to implement [TwitterStream](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/TwitterStream.html) filter or sample function.
My java code is as follows:

```java
package tweettMap;
import twitter4j.*;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;
public class stream {
    public void getStreams()
        throws TwitterException{
    ConfigurationBuilder cb;
     cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
     cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("my key");
     cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("my consumer Secret key");
     cb.setOAuthAccessToken("my acess token");
     cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("my token key");       
     TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();      
     StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStatus(Status status) {
                System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice statusDeletionNotice)
               {
                System.out.println("Got a status deletion notice id:" + statusDeletionNotice.getStatusId());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int numberOfLimitedStatuses) {
                System.out.println("Got track limitation notice:" + numberOfLimitedStatuses);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrubGeo(long userId, long upToStatusId) {
                System.out.println("Got scrub_geo event userId:" + userId + " upToStatusId:" + upToStatusId);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStallWarning(StallWarning warning) {
                System.out.println("Got stall warning:" + warning);
            }

            @Override
            public void onException(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        };          
                 double boundingBox[][]= {{-180, -90}, {180, 90}}; 
                 FilterQuery filtro = new FilterQuery();
                  filtro.locations(boundingBox);
                  twitterStream.addListener(listener);
                  twitterStream.filter(filtro);         
    }
}
```

**Error thrown is as follows:**

```java
com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: /tweettmap
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:429)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkAccess(DevAppServerFactory.java:454)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(ThreadGroup.java:315)
    at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:389)
    at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:349)
    at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:444)
    at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl$TwitterStreamConsumer.<init>(TwitterStreamImpl.java:505)
    at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl$7.<init>(TwitterStreamImpl.java:308)
    at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl.filter(TwitterStreamImpl.java:308)
    at tweettMap.stream.getStreams(stream.java:92)
    at tweettMap.TweettMapServlet.doGet(TweettMapServlet.java:73)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:491)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Comment: The Twitter4J site says it supports Google App Engine and there is a specific [twitter4j-appengine](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/tree/master/twitter4j-appengine) module on GitHub. I don't know if that supports the streaming api... it might be worth [asking this on their forums](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/twitter4j).